# Can I redefine a variable in terms of itself with \def?

Tags: errors

So I have a couple variables defined in a TikZ image (specifically an x-value and a y-value of a point), and I'd like to be able to redefine them by adding some value to each. But I'm running into two problems:

1. LaTeX doesn't want to do mathematical operations on variables. So `\def \a{1+1}` literally sets \a to "1+1" instead of 2.
2. Redefining a variable in terms of itself throws LaTeX into (what I think is) a recursion error. `\def  \a{\a + 1}` leads to the error "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]."

I'd ideally like to do this:

```
\def \a{0}

% lots of code here

\def \a{\a + 2}

% after this line, I want \a to equal 2, not "0 + 2"
```

Is there a way to get this result with pgf or something?

Comment: why not go for pgfmathsetmacro

Comment: You cannot `\def` a macro in terms of itself. You have two options: `\edef`, if possible. Or else, `\let\sva\a` and the `\def\a` in terms of `\sva`.

Answer (score 3):

You can perform elementary numeric expressions using `\numexpr<expr>`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\aaa{0}
\aaa
% lots of code here

\edef\aaa{\number\numexpr\aaa + 2}
\aaa

% after this line, I want \a to equal 2, not "0 + 2"

\end{document}
```

The above outputs `0` and `2`.

Better would be to use [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp); elementary integer calculations are possible via `\inteval`, otherwise you can use `\fpeval`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

\def\aaa{0}
\aaa
% lots of code here

\edef\aaa{\inteval{\aaa + 2}}
\aaa

% after this line, I want \a to equal 2, not "0 + 2"

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried xfp and it works like a charm.